# Javascript - use string as object reference

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have a bunch of objects, and within these objects is the string "id" (which is the same as the object name) how can I use this string to reference the object?

Example:

```
//These objects are tests - note the id's are the same as the object name

var test1 = {
    id : "test1",
    data : "Test 1 test 1 test 1"
}

var test2 = {
    id : "test2",
    data : "Test 2 test 2 test 2"
}


/* ----- My Function   ----- */

var myObj = null;

function setMyObj(obj){
   myObj = obj;
}

setMyObj(test1);

/* ----- My Function   ----- */
```

Now, if I call the following:

```
myObj.id;
```

The Result is "test1" (a string).
If I want to use this to get the data from test1, how would I do so?

```
"myObj.id".data
[myObj.id].data
```

^^^

These don't work!

Cheers,
Rich

Comment: `myObj.data` should do the job.

Comment: Hey Furqan - that get's me myObj data - I want test1's data (which could have changed in the meantime)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your variables are defined on a global scope, the following works

```
window[ myObj.id ].data
```

If you are in a function's scope, things get a lot harder. Easiest way then is to define your objects in a specific namespace on window and retrieve the objects similar to the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Store test1 and test2 in a key-value collection (aka an object.) Then access it like:

```
collection[myObj.id].data
```

Comment: Fwiw, this is the solution I'm going with, but I think @sirko answer the question exactly how it was posed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to something using a variable, then make that something an object property, not a variable. If they are sufficiently related to be accessed in that way, then they are sufficiently related to have a proper data structure to express that relationship.

```
var data = {
    test1: {
        id: "test1",
        data: "Test 1 test 1 test 1"
    },
    test2: {
        id: "test2",
        data: "Test 2 test 2 test 2"
    }
};
```

Then you can access:

```
alert( data[myObj.id] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers all, thanks for the help, in case any one finds this in future, this is how I'm going to use it:

```
var parent = {}

parent.test1 = {
    id : "test1",
    data : "Test 1 test 1 test 1"
}

parent.test2 = {
    id : "test2",
    data : "Test 2 test 2 test 2"
}


var myObj = null;

function setMyObj(obj){
   myObj = obj;
}


setMyObj(parent.test1);

parent[myObj.id] = null;
//Test1 object is now null, not myObj!
```