# how to reference object as string name

Tags: javascript

I need to reference my object as a string  but I am having issues.

ideally I would like this to work `['mystring'].myproperty;` but obviously this wont work.

Is there another way besides the options below?

```
// auto generated ecample/////////////

var mystring = {
myproperty :'test'

}
/////////////////////////////////////

var optionA =mystring.myproperty; // works


var optionB = window['mystring'].myproperty; //gives issues


var optionC = eval('mystring').myproperty; //gives issues


var optionD = ['mystring'].myproperty; // wont work
```

Comment: `optionC` no use; overkill. `optionD` you're creating an array with one string inside, and the array doesn't have a `myproperty` method. So use A or B, those are correct.

Comment: `mystring` is not property of the `window` `object`

Comment: I've used B and I've had issues, also want to find a way to do this. OP wants to use e.g. var x = "mystring"; alert(x.myproperty);

Comment: If you don't create all global variables you entirely avoid this issue. `var MY = { mystring: { myproperty: 'test' } }; MY['mystring'].myproperty`

Comment: thanks,  change it to answer and I'll mark it

Comment: @steo: if it's a browser environment and the variable is defined globally `mystring` would indeed be a property of the `window` object.

Comment: but the variable in this case is not defined as global

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are defined on a global scope, the following works

```
window[ mystring.myproperty ].data
```

If you are in a function's scope, things get a lot harder. Easiest way then is to define your objects in a specific namespace on window and retrieve the objects similar to the above code.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Javascript - use string as object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102611/javascript-use-string-as-object-reference)